# Limit case of the algebra of limits

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am new in this site and I hope the formulation of my question could be quite good.
I am studying the limits of sequences in order to be able then to study also the limits of the functions.
In the so called algebra of limits it is stated that: if $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=b\in\mathbb{R}$ then $a_n+b_n\to a+b$. If instead $a=b=\pm \infty$ then $a_n+b_n\to \pm \infty$.
What I have not understood, maybe it is a very common and trivial question so sorry in advance, is:

if $a=+\infty$ and $b=-\infty$ then I have an indeterminate form of type $\infty-\infty$ and so I can't apply the algebra of limits, right?

$\textbf{So this means that is not true that $\lim_{n\to \infty}n-\lim_{n\to \infty}n=\lim_{n\to \infty}n-n=0$, right?}$ This would be due by the fact I am stating that the indeterminate form $\infty-\infty$ is $0$, but this is not necessarily true. So the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}n-\lim_{n\to \infty}n$ can't be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression $\lim_{n\to\infty}n-\lim_{n\to\infty}n$ means $\infty-\infty$ (since $\lim_{n\to\infty}n=\infty$) and therefore it is undefined. In particular, it is not equal to $0$.

Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n-\lim_{n\to\infty}n$ is *not* an indeterminate form. What is an indeterminate form is $\lim_{n\to\infty}(n-n)$ (which turns out to be equal to $0$).

Comment: Ok very thanks so this mean that when I have a difference of two divergent sequence (for instance both to $+\infty$) then I can't split the limit right? And why $\lim n-\lim n$ is not indeterminate if it is $\infty-\infty$?

Comment: That's too much general. You cannot do that when one of them diverges to $\infty$ and the other one diverges to $-\infty$. But you *can* do it, say in the case $\lim_{n\to\infty}n-\lim_{n\to\infty}(-n)$; this is equal to $\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\lim n-n$ then it is proved to be $0$ whereas $\lim n-\lim n$ can't be solved?

Comment: I would never say that $\lim_{n\to\infty}n-\lim_{n\to\infty}n$ cannot be solved since there is nothing to be solved here. What happens is that the expression $\lim_{n\to\infty}n-\lim_{n\to\infty}n$ has no meaning.

Comment: Ah ok so this means that the expression $\infty-\infty$ that we use for $\lim n-n$ is only to indicate thta it is an indeterminate form but really this limit is $0$. Instead $lim n-\lim n=\infty-\infty$ but  $\infty-\infty$ is something that it is neither $\infty$ or a real number, right? Sorry for the maybe stupid questions but I am not sure to have understood well

Comment: It seems that everyting is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n$ has no meaning as we don't define $\infty-\infty$ in extended real numbers system, so the formula is not applicable.

But it is not hard to prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}-\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}=\infty$ if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_{n}=\infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_{n}=-\infty$, so one shall only avoid the form like $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a would like to give you +1 but my reputation does not allow this to me...:(